# Two equal variables not triggering an if() statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a bit rusty so there's probably something obvious, but I'm setting up a form where I want to hide a row when a checkbox is ticked but the if statement I'm using to check the actual contents of the cell against a predetermined "VALUE" is not triggering. The log above prints both out as "true", but then the if statement is never entered. What am I missing?

```
var SHEET = "Requests"; //Sheet Name
var VALUE = "true"; //Value that will hide the row
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 11 //Column K
 
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Setters and getters woohoo
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
    var cellValue = cell.getValue(); //Gets current cell and the value in it
    
    //Ensure we are looking at the correct column.
    if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){
      console.log("Cell Contains " + cellValue + " and VALUE is " + VALUE);
      
      if(cellValue == VALUE){

        console.log("Rows Hidden");
        activeSheet.hideRow(cell);
      };
    };
  };
}[Log showing both printed true][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAvpm.png
```

Comment: The script you've added on your post is incomplete (no initialization of "activeSheet", "ss", "COLUMN_NUMBER" & "VALUE"). Please include the complete function to precisely replicate your issue and be able to pin point the what's wrong in your script. And also please include at least a screenshot of the execution logs where you see the "The log above prints both out as "true" "

Comment: If we can't reproduce the problem then it's not a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks guys, it's my first post so still figuring out the right way to post - I've edited now with the full function and added a photo of the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Findings:**

The `VALUE` (contains a `string` value "true") is not matching the value of `cellValue` (contains a `boolean` value true) on Line 17 and it is the reason why your code does not work:

```
if(cellValue == VALUE){

    console.log("Rows Hidden");
    activeSheet.hideRow(cell);
  };
```

**Solution:**

I've replicated your script and I was able to make it work by changing the predefined `VALUE`

from:

```
var VALUE = "true";
```

to (a boolean variable) :

```
var VALUE = true;
```

**Recommendation:**

I also have simplified your script (due to nested `if` statements) and changed your function from `onOpen` to `OnEdit` because [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started) will not run your `if` statement due to `ss.getActiveCell()` for the `cell` variable, which will need you to highlight/select a cell but it is not possible when opening your spreadsheet file.

Using `OnEdit` function will auto-hide the checkbox right after you've checked it on your sheet:

```
var SHEET = "Requests";
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 11;
var VALUE = true;

function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();

  if(SHEET == ss.getName() & cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER & cellValue == VALUE){
    console.log("Cell Contains " + cellValue + " and VALUE is " + cellValue);      
    console.log("Rows Hidden");
    ss.hideRow(cell);
  };
}
```